# Click+CTRL key to select a row and then add a CSS class to all rows below it until a row with another CSS class is found with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a JavaScript app which has Project Task records that allow you to drag and drop to reposition there sort order.

**This is a long detailed post with code and demo.  My question is at the bottom...**

There is also a 2nd type of task record which acts as a dummy Task list heading so that you can drag and drop list heading records in between tasks to separate and create more organized task lists.

This screenshot shows a little bit of some of the click and drag and drop features which include:

- Single click on a Task row Drag handle adds a `.selected` CSS class to the row which changes the background color to show that it is "Selected".  Once a Task row is selected you can also click and hold on the Drag handle while dragging to row to a new position vertically.
- Holding down the `CTRL` keyboard key while clicking a task row drag handle allows you to select multiple rows.  Once you have more then 1 row selected, you can click and drag and drop multiple rows to a new sort order position.
- After 1 or more rows are selected, clicking any other drag handle will de-select all the rows and then select the one you clicked on.  That is unless you hold the `CTRL` key down to do the multi-selection feature.
- Dragging a Tsk Header row or any row for that matter allows you to organize the order to create **Task Lists**

---

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/xhmb2ba1/

---

[image]

---

**JavaScript - Adds drag and drop + click to select multiple rows**

```
// Handle Project Task Drag and Drop Sorting on Task Edit Screen.
$("#project_tasks").on('click', '.handle', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
}).sortable({
    handle: '.handle',
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    delay: 150, //Needed to prevent accidental drag when trying to select
    revert: 0,
    helper: function (e, item) {
        var helper = $('<div/>');
        if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
            item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
        var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
        item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
        return helper.append(elements);
    },
    stop: function (e, info) {
        info.item.after(info.item.data('multidrag')).remove();
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        updateSortOrderNumbers();
    }
});

function updateSortOrderNumbers(){
  showTaskUnSavedChangesHeaderBar();
  jQuery('.sortable div.task_row').each(function(idx) {
    var inputField = jQuery(this).find("[id^='sort_order']");
    jQuery(inputField).val(idx+1);
  });
}
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<div id="project_tasks" class="tasks_block sortable list ui-sortable" style="display: block;">

    <!-- TASK HEADING ROW -->
    <div id="task_11" class="heading-row task_row">
        <span class="handle" title="Drag and Drop to Reorder Tasks"></span>
        <input name="sort_order_11" id="sort_order_11" class="sort_order" size="15" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input name="heading_11" id="heading_11" class="heading" size="15" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input name="name_11" id="name_11" class="task-heading name" size="45" type="text" value="List Heading 1" placeholder="Type a Project Task List Heading Here..." style="cursor: auto; ">
         <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>

    <div id="task_12" class="task_row">
        <span class="handle" title="Drag and Drop to Reorder Tasks"></span>
        <input name="sort_order_12" id="sort_order_12" class="sort_order" size="15" type="hidden" value="2">
        <div class="task-name-wrap">
            <input class="name" name="name_12" id="name_12" placeholder="Name:" size="45" type="text" value="Task record 2">
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>

    <div id="task_12" class="task_row">
        <span class="handle" title="Drag and Drop to Reorder Tasks"></span>
        <input name="sort_order_12" id="sort_order_12" class="sort_order" size="15" type="hidden" value="2">
        <div class="task-name-wrap">
            <input class="name" name="name_12" id="name_12" placeholder="Name:" size="45" type="text" value="Task record 3">
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>

    <!-- TASK HEADING ROW -->
    <div id="task_11" class="heading-row task_row">
        <span class="handle" title="Drag and Drop to Reorder Tasks"></span>
        <input name="sort_order_11" id="sort_order_11" class="sort_order" size="15" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input name="heading_11" id="heading_11" class="heading" size="15" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input name="name_11" id="name_11" class="task-heading name" size="45" type="text" value="List Heading 2" placeholder="Type a Project Task List Heading Here..." style="cursor: auto; ">
         <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>


    <div id="task_12" class="task_row">
        <span class="handle" title="Drag and Drop to Reorder Tasks"></span>
        <input name="sort_order_12" id="sort_order_12" class="sort_order" size="15" type="hidden" value="2">
        <div class="task-name-wrap">
            <input class="name" name="name_12" id="name_12" placeholder="Name:" size="45" type="text" value="Task record 6">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="task_12" class="task_row">
        <span class="handle" title="Drag and Drop to Reorder Tasks"></span>
        <input name="sort_order_12" id="sort_order_12" class="sort_order" size="15" type="hidden" value="2">
        <div class="task-name-wrap">
            <input class="name" name="name_12" id="name_12" placeholder="Name:" size="45" type="text" value="Task record 7">
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

---

**QUESTION: New Click to select all Task in a Task List feature:**

What I would like to do is add the capability to `CTRL + Click` on a Task Heading row drag picker image and have it "select" (add the .select CSS class) to all Task rows that are below that Task heading row but before the next task heading.

Since a Task heading row is no different than a regular Task record, there is no parent/child hierarchy so that complicates things.  The HTML above shows there are **2 Task Heading rows**.  The 1st and the 4th.

So `CTRL+Click` on the 1st Tash heading row would need to add the CSS class `selected` to row 1, 2, and 3 to select the Task heading row plus its 2 "child" rows.

Is it possible to select all the Fake child Task rows of a Task heading row?

Demo of existing functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/xhmb2ba1/

---

**UPDATE:**

I just came across this jQuery function https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ which might be the ticket to my solution

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this jQuery function https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ which seems to be the way to go in my situation.

This line selects all child items when `CTRL+clicking` a Task heading.

```
// select child task under a task row until next task row is reached
if ($(this).parent().hasClass('heading-row'))
{
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $(this).parent().nextUntil(".heading-row" ).addClass("selected");
    }else{
        //$(this).parent().nextUntil(".heading-row" ).toggleClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().nextUntil(".heading-row" ).removeClass("selected");
    }
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/xhmb2ba1/8/

[image]